# Erro comunicação Socket

Tags: java, android

Tenho este trecho de código:

```
public class Consulta extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Socket cliente = new Socket("10.20.1.100", 12345);
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
            List<PessoaMOD> pessoas = (List) entrada.readObject();
            for (PessoaMOD p : pessoas) {
                Log.d("teste", "ID: " + p.getId() + " - Nome: " + p.getNome());
            }
            entrada.close();
            Log.d("teste", "Conexão encerrada");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("teste", "Erro: " + e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

private void botaoComunicarServidor() {
    Button btComunicarServidor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btComunicarServidor);
    btComunicarServidor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Consulta().execute();
        }
    });
}

public class PessoaMOD implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public PessoaMOD(int id, String nome){
        setId(id);
        setNome(nome);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Dá o seguinte erro:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PessoaMOD`

Em uma aplicação java, este mesmo código que uso no Android funciona...

No MANIFEST já liberei acesso para Internet:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

-----------------EDIT------------------

Descobri o erro, mas não sei como resolver... haha

O erro acontece porque o nome do pacote da classe PessoaMOD no servidor é diferente do nome do pacote da aplicação cliente. Eu coloquei o mesmo nome de pacote e funcionou. Mas eu troquei o nome só para testar, não posso trocar o nome do pacote... Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Ele ñ tá conseguindo transformar em **PessoaMOD**! Você consegue debugar pra ver o que ele retorna no **entrada.readObject()**???

Comment: Descobri o erro, mas não sei como resolver... haha

O erro acontece porque o nome do pacote da classe PessoaMOD no servidor é diferente do nome do pacote da aplicação cliente. Eu coloquei o mesmo nome de pacote e funcionou. Mas eu troquei o nome só para testar, não posso trocar o nome do pacote... Como posso resolver isso?